# Element in 2D Array Missing?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm using function to assign the patterns of my 2D arrays. All the other arrays are displaying as it should except for my 'ans' array (the last row's dash is missing). Im guessing the problem is because of the 'pat2match' function (merges all the patterns). Because if i don's assign 'ans' to that 'function' and print an empty pattern array, all the dashes shows.

The function that merges the patterns:

```
char pat2match(char mypattern[13][13], char pat1[13][13], char pat2[13][13], 
        char pat3[13][13], char pat4[13][13], char pat5[13][13])
{
    int r,c;

    overlap(mypattern,pat5);
    overlap(mypattern,pat2);
    overlap(mypattern,pat4);
    overlap(mypattern,pat3);
    return overlap(mypattern,pat1);
}
```

Assigning the 'ans':

```
mytile(ans);
for(r=0;r<13;r++)
{
    for(c=0;c<13;c++)
    {
        ans[r][c] = pat2match(ans,pattern1,pattern2,pattern3,pattern4,pattern5);
    }
}
```

The overlap function:

```
char overlap(char pat1[13][13], char pat2[13][13])
{
    int r,c;

    for(r=0;r<13;r++)
    {
        //printf("|");
        for(c=0;c<13;c++)
        {
            if(pat1[r][c] == ' ' || pat2[r][c] != ' ')
            {
                pat1[r][c] = pat2[r][c];
            }
            //printf(" %c ", pat1[r][c]);
        }
        //printf("|\n");
    }
    return pat1[r][c];
}
```

the empty pattern (the dash is like its border) :

```
void mytile(char pat[13][13])
{
    int r,c;

    for(r=0;r<13;r++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<13;c++)
        {
            if(r==0 || r==12)
            {
                pat[r][c] = '-';
            }
            else
            {
                pat[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uuh? Which elements in which 2D array are giving you problems, and just what type of errors or output do you receive?, what do you expect to get? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my 'ans' array (the last row's dash is missing). The output should have the last dash showing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from `overlap` is undefined behavior:

```
return pat1[r][c];
```

When this return statement is executed, both `r` and `c` are 13.  Neither can be greater than 12.  It is indexing past the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! But now, all the empty spaces becomes '-'. My guess is in the if statement,  i need to add another argument?

Comment: Well, if `overlap` sees a space and a hyphen at the same position in the two arrays, it will use the hyphen.  But it looks like the first version of `mytile` is assigning the same value to all elements (and calling `pat2match` once for every element).

Comment: Oh, so how can I fix this? I'm really stuck right now

Comment: So my task is to write a program that ask for users to combine 5 patterns to match with a given pattern. so what i did was merge 5 individual patterns that i already designed and each time the users choose a pattern, the pattern they choose will overlap the current pattern. so the 'mytile' is the user's initial pattern (no pattern just the dash as borders).

Comment: Yup, I did. I removed the mytile(ans). That's what you meant right? Or do you mean remove the mytile function?

Comment: Oh, my mistake - I didn't look at it carefully enough, I thought you were defining `mytile`, not calling it - ok that makes more sense now!  Ok, put that call back in, but remove the next loop *following* the call.  Just replace it the entire nested loop with a single call to `pat2match`.  Does that make sense?  You don't need the return value from it.  So you just want (1) the call to `mytile(ans)`, followed by (2) a single call to `pat2match` (ignore the return value, it should be a void function).

Comment: But by doing that, i cannot print the pat2match right? Is there any way I can send you my whole code to you? Maybe that way you can understand more what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well, the idea was that you would first initialize `arr` with `mytile`, then update it with `pat2match`.  After that, I think `arr` should contain what you want to print.  Both `overlap` and `pat2match` would be `void` functions that don't return anything, since they would operate directly on `arr`.

Comment: i think i get what you mean, i'll give it a try. also, do you mean arr or ans? ans right